# Is it possible to run a playbook in "pull mode"?

Tags: ansible

I have playbooks which I start on a master host and which run specific actions on remote hosts. This is a "push" mode - the activity is initiated by the master host.

Several of my hosts are down at a given time and obviously fail to run the playbook when in such a state. This leads to hosts which are up-to-date, while others are not.

To fix this I could run the playbook on the master host in a regular way (via `cron` for instance) but this is not particularly effective.

**Is there a built-in way in Ansible to reverse the flow,** that is to initiate from a remote host a playbook available on the master, to run it on that remote host?

I can imagine that the remote host could ssh to the master (at boot time for instance) and then trigger the playbook with the host as a parameter (or something around that idea) but I would definitely prefer to use an Ansible feature instead of reinventing it.

Answer (score 5):

There is a script called [ansible-pull](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_intro.html#ansible-pull) which reverses the default push architecture of Ansible. There is also an [example playbook](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/ansible_pull.yml) from the Ansible developers available.

Answer (score 4):

The use of `ansible-pull` mode is really simple and straight-forward, this example might help you:

```
ansible-pull -d /root/playbooks -i 'localhost,' -U git@bitbucket.org:arbabnazar/pull-test.git --accept-host-key
```

options detail:

```
1. --accept-host-key: adds the hostkey for the repo url if not already added
 2. -U: URL of the playbook repository
 3. -d: directory to checkout repository to
 4. –i localhost,: This option indicates the inventory that needs to be considered. 
                   Since we're only concerned about one host, we use -i localhost,.
```

For detail, please refer to this [tutorial](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2016/05/15/autoscaling-with-aws-instances-using-ansible-pull/)