# Possible to configure synchronous "fire and forget" tasks with Ansible?

Tags: python-2.7, ansible

I have several long-running Ansible tasks where the SSH connection will often timeout before they complete. The tasks need to run in the specified order of the playbook.

Ideally, I would like to configure the playbook as a series of "fire and forget" tasks, with the final task being an SNS notification that everything completed. As in, I'd like to start the playbook, and be able to turn off my computer (the control machine), and have the playbook continue progress on the server.

As far as I can tell, the only way to do this is by making the tasks asynchronous with polling disabled (and a long time limit). However, setting the tasks as async is not helpful, because I need task execution blocked until the previous task completes.

I've explored registering a variable, and then setting `when: variable.finished` on the next task, but this causes the task to be skipped. I've explored `wait_for` and `block` but these don't seem to do what I'm intending.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to run a playbook in "pull mode"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38663591/is-it-possible-to-run-a-playbook-in-pull-mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some deliberation, I decided that what I actually needed was the ability to run an entire playbook as a "fire and forget" asynchronous task.

To do this, I made a new asynchronous ansible task that would make the server run the playbook on itself, for example:

```
- hosts: server
  tasks:
    - name: Run a Playbook
      command: ansible-playbook {{playbook}}
      async: 3600
      poll: 0
```

And modified the host of the original playbook to use `localhost` (since it is now running on itself).